# asp mvc4 html helper not navigating to expected page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I am generating a link using the below code

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Index", "Properties")
```

on the client side this renders

```
<a href="/Properties">Search</a>
```

Looking at the above link I expected to got to

`controller: Properties`

`action: Index`

When I click the link I am navigated to `http://localhost:49878/Properties/` and I get the error

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>   The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

If I navigate to `http://localhost:49878/Properties/Index` I get my expected page.

Why?

I have looked at `RouteConfig` to try and understand this and looking at the default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I thought the below would resolve the issue, but it didn't, why?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Search",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Properties", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Do you have a folder in your solution named `Properties`?

Comment: No, but I do have a controller named properties

Comment: You sure? (by default VS will create one). And you would get the same error if you were no navigate to (say) `.../Content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only see a Properties folder in your solution like this:

[image: solution]

But if open project folder like this:

[image: filedisk]

You can see two folders in two paths:

**Root**

[image: rootfolder]

**View folder**

[image: viewfolder]

The routing system checks the file system to see if a URL matches a file/folder on the disk. If it finds a match, the routing is ignored and the request bypassed any route entries so that the file will be served directly.

To fix this you can set the `RouteExistingFiles` property to `true` in your `RouteConfig`:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Properties as it's the name of the folder that has AssemblyInfo.cs . So kind of restricted name.

Add this to

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

RegisterRoutes in RouteConfig to ignore physical paths (although this will have some complications for static files, do test it thoroughly).

Better approach is renaming your controller and use it not sure if there is something else that can be done.